# BrowserSync not reloading on change with Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I am having an issue where BrowserSync does not reload on change. From what I can tell, it hangs on reload when a change has been made. The changes are shown when I refresh the browser manually. Here is my source code for my gulpfile as a reference

```
    const {src, dest, watch, series, parallel} = require('gulp')
    const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
    const cssnano = require('cssnano')
    const concat = require('gulp-concat')
    const postcss = require('gulp-postcss')
    const replace = require('gulp-replace')
    const sass = require('gulp-sass')
    const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
    const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
    const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create()

    const files = {
        scssPath: 'app/scss/**/*.scss',
        jsPath: 'app/js/**/*.js',
        htmlPath: 'app/index.html'
    }

    const scssTask = () => {
        return src(files.scssPath)
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ]))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
            .pipe(dest('dist'))
            .pipe(browsersync.stream({stream: 'true'}))
    }

    const jsTask = () => {
        return src(files.jsPath)
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(concat('main.js'))
            .pipe(dest('dist'))
            .pipe(browsersync.stream({stream: 'true'}))
    }

    const serverRefresh = (done) => {
        browsersync.reload()
        done()
    }

    const serve = (done) => {
        browsersync.init({
            server:{
                baseDir: './'
            }
        })
        done()
    }

    const watchTask = () => {
        watch([files.scssPath, files.jsPath], series(parallel(scssTask, jsTask), serverRefresh))
    }

    exports.default = series(parallel(scssTask, jsTask), serve, watchTask)
```

Please let me know where I can fix this as I have tried different approaches and have not found a solution yet.

Comment: In the browser console, do you get any error messages?

Comment: Also, simplify your code by removing any use of the `serverRefresh` task - you already reload the server in your other tasks so doing it again could cause some issues (especially the hang you are seeing).

Comment: And use `.pipe(reload({ stream: true }));` instead of the `.pipe(browsersync.stream({stream: 'true'}))` calls.  `stream` doesn't take those options you used.

Comment: In the terminal I get no errors, I do get the refresh browsers line but it hangs and does not return a finished task when it sends (not sure if this is intended or not. I'm not home at the moment but I'll integrate your suggestions. Thanks!